# Two-step remote ssh without password

Tags: ssh, password, remote

I'm looking to ssh from my localhost to a remote server, and from there to a remote computer. I currently have it set up so that the remote computer and remote server have passwordless ssh-ing set up between them, but if I ssh from my localhost into the server, and then try to ssh to the computer from there, I get:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa': 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
```

If I try to ssh from a terminal open on the remote server to the remote computer, it works just fine. Does it have something to do with my display not being `:0.0`, or something else entirely? I've tried `xhost +local:` but been lost past that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both systems have the public key of your local system use `-A`.

From `ssh(1)`

> ```
> -A      Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This
>         can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.
> ```

Also be aware of this warning:

> ```
>         Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
>         ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
>         agent's UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent through the
>         forwarded connection.  An attacker cannot obtain key material from
>         the agent, however they can perform operations on the keys that
>         enable them to authenticate using the identities loaded into the
>         agent.
> ```

The result is that when you auth against the second host the auth is forwarded all the way back to the host where you physically reside.

Example:

```
me@host0:~ $ ssh -A host1
Last login: Thu Jun 14 11:31:53 2012 from 2001:db8::b0
me@host1:~ $ ssh -A host2
Last login: Thu Jun 14 11:41:05 2012 from 2001:db8::b1
me@host3:~ $ ssh -A host3
Last login: Tue Jun 12 10:46:50 2012 from 2001:db8::b2
me@host3:~ $
```

Comment: So in the event I want to make this extensible and have five or six computers log in to the server (with one username), and then have passwordless access to the remote computer, I'd have to add all of their public keys to both server and remote computer?

Comment: No. Add the public key for only the computer you are physically using to all remote systems.

Comment: I meant if I wanted my laptop, work computer, and tablet to all log into a central server, and from there have passwordless access to another computer, I'd have to pass around all three public keys, which I was hoping to avoid, but should work. Thanks

Comment: Yes, true. Or you can use the same secret key on each (although not recommended). I use cfengine to distribute my public key to all hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Your agent is unable to pass authentication on to the remote computer. You can port-forward a connection to connect directly to the remote machine if you would like.

See [this article on SSH multi-hop](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) and skip to the section about `ProxyCommand`

in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remotecomputername
  ProxyCommand ssh -q remoteservername nc -q0 remotecomputername 22
```

Comment: Though very cool to know, it's still giving me a Permission Denied error. I've also tried adding the flags -t and -ax to no avail, and copying the id_dsa files to my localhost didn't help either.

Comment: Though the private key unlocks automatically for terminals on the remote server, it doesn't seem to transfer that to my remote login. Is it even possible to do that?